# Using a URL as a URL parameter in Django

Tags: django, django-urls

In my **models**, I have the following:

```
class Content(models.Model):
    address = models.URLField(unique=True)
```

In my **urls**, I have this pattern:

```
url(r'^content_detail/(?P<address>[a-zA-Z-_./:0-9-_+=?;~@#%^&*(){}|`<>]+)/$', views.content_detail),
```

Yes, seriously, thats the pattern Im using. Basically, i took a look at all the characters that can be used in a URL, and made the pattern. Now, my question is, will it work? Its been working fine in my testing but I am no regex expert. Any way to improve this? If possible, can anyone give me a django url specific regex for URLs? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would recommend to pass the url in a GET parameter rather than putting it in the url path.

Comment: Interesting. Can you elaborate why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have added all the possible symbols, alphabets and numbers in your URL.

```
url(r'^content_detail/(?P<address>.*)/$', views.content_detail),
```

This allows all characters in your URL.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.+` as at-least something is required.

Comment: Yes.. Sorry I did not notice the + in question.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex will fail on IDNs (Internationalized Domain Names) containing Unicode characters. I think the easiest way would be matching on `.+` as Aswin Kumar K P wrote in his answer, then validating the captured pattern using Django's URLValidator. You can find Django's regular expressions for URLs in that validator's source code: [URLValidator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/core/validators/#URLValidator)